# TraMineR graphics not reactive to layout of R

Tags: r, layout, sequence, par, traminer

```
##PACKAGES
library(tidyverse,quietly=TRUE)
library(TraMineR)
library(WeightedCluster, quietly = TRUE)
library(viridis)
library(seqhandbook, quietly = TRUE)
```

Here is a representation of my dataset:

```
mydata<-structure(list(T1 = structure(c("ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                                "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                                "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                                "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                                "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                                "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN"
), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T2 = structure(c("ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T3 = structure(c("ANN",          "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T4 = structure(c("ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T5 = structure(c("ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T6 = structure(c("ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T7 = structure(c("ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T8 = structure(c("ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL"), label = "Type chir. bariat."), 
T9 = structure(c("ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                 "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T10 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T11 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."), 
T12 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T13 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."), 
T14 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."), 
T15 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."), 
T16 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T17 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T18 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T19 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat."),
T20 = structure(c("ANN", 
                  "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ABL", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "BPG", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "SLE", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", 
                  "ANN", "ANN", "ANN", "SLE"), label = "Type chir. bariat.")), 
row.names = c(NA,-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to plot a graphic and the legends next to each other, since apparently, the function `seqheatmap from seqhandbook` does not display the legends.

I have done the two separately and want to do this with the function `layout from R base`

My code for the creation of sequences

```
# ALPHABETS AND LABELS
labels <- sort(c("ANN","SLE","BPG","BPD","ABL","DCD"))
Etats_lng<-c("Ablation","Anneau","Derivation bilio-pancréatique","By-pass gastrique",
             "Décès","Sleeve")

seq <- seqdef(
  mydata[, paste("T",1:20,sep = "")],
  alphabet = labels,
  states = Etats_lng,
  cpal = viridis(6, direction = -1)
)

# distances
couts <- seqsubm(seq, method = "CONSTANT", cval = 2)# Matrice des couts de substitution         
seq.dist<- seqdist(seq, method = "OM", indel = 1, sm = couts)# Distance avec optimal-Matching
seq.hclust <- hclust(as.dist(seq.dist), method = "ward.D2") #Clustering des trajectoire


#SETTING OF LAYOUT
layout.matrix <- matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
layout(mat = layout.matrix,
       widths = c(3,1) )# Widths of the two columns
layout.show(2)
```

In the first frame, I want to put the heatmap and in the second one the legends

[image]

But I doest works

```
seq_heatmap(seq, seq.hclust)
seqlegend(seq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `layout` does not work in your example because `layout` cannot be nested and `heatmap` (invoked by `seq_heatmap`) already uses `layout` to generate the Heat Map.

The only solution I see is to retrieve the source code of function `heatmap` (from **stats**), rename it say `myheatmap`, and modify it to add the display of the color legend.

To retrieve the code of `heatmap`

```
myheatmap <- heatmap
edit(myheatmap)
```

For `edit` to work, you may have to specify the editor. Alternatively, you can use `View` and copy paste the content in the editor of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  @Gilbert. But I have no idea of how to retrieve a code source from stats.

Comment: I now explain how to retrieve the code in the answer